# Insert to database gives syntax error

Tags: php, jquery, html, database

I would appreciate if anyone could tell me why Im getting a syntax error with this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                                    {   
$dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost","user1","test1","tutorial");



$stored_file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$query="INSERT INTO store (filname, uppladdare, titel) VALUES


**Line 136->**('$_POST[**file**]$stored_file','$_POST[uppladdare]','$_POST[titel]')";
    if(!mysqli_query($dbcon ,$query));
                                        }
```

*Notice: Undefined index: file in/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projekt webb/laddaupp.php on line 136*

The function works fine and Im storing all the data that I want. But Im still getting an error.
I can always "fix" this by using reporting_error. But I prefer to learn by my mistakes.

/thanks

EDIT:
The stars are not part of the coding. Just to show where the error occurs!

The final result:

$query="INSERT INTO store (filname, uppladdare, titel) 
VALUES ('$stored_file','$_POST[uppladdare]','$_POST[titel]')";

Thanks for the answers pals!:)

Comment: In English: `wtf is $_FILES["file"]`

Comment: `('$_POST[**file**]$stored_file'` WTF #2 - Post actual code.

Comment: `echo '<div style="padding:15px; background-color:white;"><pre>'.print_r($_FILES, true).'</pre></div>';` will assist with debugging

Comment: You'll also want to [`read this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: *"EDIT: The stars are not part of the coding. Just to show where the error occurs!"* - Just... **don't** - Make notes in your question, we can read. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use variable`$stored_file` Where you just stored your filename

```
$query="INSERT INTO store (filname, uppladdare, titel) 
VALUES ('$stored_file','$_POST[uppladdare]','$_POST[titel]')";
```

There is no `$_POST['file']$stored_file` in your `$_POST` As the error says there is no index for `$_POST['file']`

Comment: You welcome dude, if you feel the answer was correct don't forget to accept it so you can also help people in the future with similar problems.

Comment: Yeh, just have to wait another 3 minutes;)